github gh cli search for query
I'm looking to use the GitHub CLI (gh) or API to search within a specific organization for repositories containing "private": true in JSON files. I've tried several commands suggested by ChatGPT, but none of them have worked. Could you guide me on the correct way to do this?
i wana search for this query via gh :
org:orgname "private": true, language:JSON 
and show the output from the code catogery
i tried this command without success :
gh search repos 'org:orgname "private": true' --language "JSON" -L 1000  
Invalid search query "org:"orgname \"private\": true" language:JSON".
The listed users and repositories cannot be searched either because the resources do not exist or you do not have permission to view them.
i expect :


i have this command work :
gh api --method=GET search/code -f q='"private": true,  extension:json org:lyft' \ 
--jq '.items[] | [.repository.full_name,.path,.sha] | @tsv'
now how i can download them to my PC >
